# Probability density function of $x$ in the unit circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, probability-distributions

I'm trying to work out how to find the probability density function (PDF) for $x$ values on the unit circle - not within the unit circle but on the edge.

The reason for doing so is that I'm trying to reduce a problem where a uniform distribution of random angle gives the result I'm looking for, but I'd like to try to reduce the problem to one dimension dealing only with $x$ values.

I'm at the point now where if I can find the PDF I can use inverse transform sampling to redistribute uniform random $x$ values and it should work - I think!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: If $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$, what is the distribution of $\cos \theta$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @ZubinMukerjee.  
I should mention that I am not particularly well versed in probability distributions, and am learning on the fly to try and solve this problem. 
I should also have specified in my original post that I'll use my redistributed $x$ values to find an approximation of $\pi$, so - mostly out of interest - am trying to avoid the use of $\pi$ or $\theta$ in my working. I've been able to figure it out using uniformly distributed $x$ and $y$ values, but am interested to see if it can be done using only $x$, leaving $y$ and $\theta$ implicit.
Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not really the person to ask about probability distributions either, but if I had to guess I'd say it's difficult to avoid using an explicit variable and distribution for the angle (e.g. $\theta$) if you want to be rigorous about the "random angle" ...

If you're not in any particular hurry I can put a reputation bounty or whatever on this question in a few days, which will make more people look at it and hopefully answer it fully.

Comment: Hi @ZubinMukerjee, sorry for the late reply. That would be great if you're still willing/it's still possible! Thanks.

Comment: @Stephen Are you still interested in a solution?